# Change URL on GIF animation end

Tags: javascript, html, url, gif, animated-gif

I am trying to change the URL of a website once a GIF has reached its last frame. What I got to, is that I can use the [libgif.js setup](https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js).

However I am having difficulties making it work and figuring out the components. There are a couple of example suggestions, but all I need it to do is check if the GIF has finished and if so go to another URL.

The following code is what I have gotten to so far, it loads the GIF but nothing happens, other than it plays in a loop, even though the GIF isn't supposed to loop. But no URL change or anything.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: the site now just doesn't load and goes directly to "unsafe website" message from browsers.

```
<html lang="en">
    
  <head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./libgif.js"></script>
    
  </head>
    
  <body>
        
    <img id="taliAni" src="LogoAnimation2.gif" rel:animated_src="LogoAnimation2.gif" 
      rel:auto_play="1"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sup1 = new SuperGif({ gif: document.getElementById('taliAni') } );
        sup1.on_end(window.location.href = "https://www.website.com/";);
    </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not reloading the current page (restarting the animation)?

Comment: @isherwood Good point, however to me it doesn't seem like it, as to my knowledge if this was the case it would have the usual reload message in the left corner stating which link it reloads to like on any page. But I could of course be wrong, it just doesn't seem like it.

Comment: I also now just checked the console and it says the following "Uncaught TypeError: sup1.on_end is not a function" but the function is from the GIF js library

Comment: Well there's a clue. It's not finding the library or you're using it incorrectly.

Comment: Have you verified that the library is loading?

Comment: The library seems to be loading, then it is more a case of whether I am using it correctly.

Comment: The code has now been changed, as it said "sup1.on_end" wasn't a function. But now whenever the page is loaded, it goes into the "this page is unsage" message from all browsers?